# Importing sbt to scalaIDE

Tags: scala, sbt, scala-ide

I am new to scala. I have source code in the sbt structure as following:

```
base/lib
    /project
    /src/main
    /src/test
    /target
```

How should I import them to ScalaIDE (which use Eclipse)?

I tried to import the source, but no matter which folder I choose (base, src), no scala project is detected.

Answer (score 2):

Use [sbteclipse](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse#sbteclipse-). From the README:

1. Add sbteclipse to your plugin definition file (or create one if doesn't exist). You can use either the global file (for version 0.13 and up) at `~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/plugins.sbt` or the project-specific file at `PROJECT_DIR/project/plugins.sbt`.

   For the latest version:

   ```
   addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0")
   ```
2. In sbt use the command eclipse to create Eclipse project files

   ```
   > eclipse
   ```
3. In Eclipse use the Import Wizard to import Existing Projects into Workspace